# Wrong version of OpenSSL shown when using PowerShell script "OpenSSL version"

Tags: windows, openvpn, openssl, windows-server-2019

I was following a [video tutorial on installing OpenVPN Server](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UItFm-8MvQ4) on Windows Server 2019 and for that I needed to install OpenSSL. I downloaded and successfully installed version 3.0.1, but as soon as I run the script `openssl version`, it shows

> OpenSSL 1.0.1j 15 Oct 2014

AFAIK this older version was not installed on purpose.

**Is there a way to change the default version of OpenSSL or remove the old version?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have multiple versions of Openssl installed, which is not unusual as it's bundled with quite a few apps - like Git or Strawberry Perl.
You can see this by running "`Get-command openssl`" to see which different installs you have.

One option to force your command prompt to use your dedicated Openssl install instead of a version bundled with other software is to give it a higher priority  your PATH variables. Edit your PATH in your environment variables `System Properties -> Advanced -> Environmental variables` and make sure your OpenSSL install is above the PATH entry for the software that bundles it.